# Python type hint instance attribute with module not instantiated

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

Suppose we have the following class.

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Dict, Any, Union


class MyClass(ABC):

    def __init__(self, name: str, filename: Union[str, PathLike]) -> None:
        """ Constructor """
        self.name = name
        self.filename = filename
        self.template: DocxTemplate

    def f1(self) -> None:
        self.template = DocxTemplate(filename)
```

I want to type `self.template` as `DocxTemplate` but instantiate it later dynamically, in `f1`. The point is that I am getting a warning in `f1` that says:

```
Instance attribute template defined outside __init__
```

I don't really know why. I also tried to type `self.template` as follows:

```
self.template: Optional[DocxTemplate] = None
```

But this forces my to check the existence of self.template in some parts of my code.

What point am I not understanding? How should it be correct?

Thanks and greetings!

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with using `self.template: Optional[DocxTemplate] = None` ?

Comment: Why are you deferring the assignment to `template`? Is your instance usable without the attribute being defined, and if so, why is it an attribute of `MyClass` in the first place (rather than some other class representing the pairing of a `MyClass` and a `DocxTemplate`)? (All of which is to say, the best way to write this depends on some context missing from the question.)

Comment: Note that the warning is from your IDE, not Python, and has nothing to do with type hinting, really. Feel free to ignore it if deferring the assignment to `template` is right for your use case.

Comment: If some part of your code is able to try to use `self.template` before `MyClass.f1` is called, then forcing you to handle the possibility of `None` is the right thing to do.

Comment: self.template is used in some different parts of my code but maybe not if a controlled exception is raised, that is the point!

Answer (score 0):

You could try making `self.template` a `property` instead of an `attribute`:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Dict, Any, Union
import os


class MyClass(ABC):

    def __init__(self, name: str, filename: Union[str, os.PathLike]) -> None:
        """ Constructor """
        self.name = name
        self.filename = filename
        self.__template = None
        
    @property
    def template(self) -> DocxTemplate:
        return self.__template

    @template.setter
    def template(self, value: DocxTemplate) -> None:
        self.__template = value
        return
    
    @template.deleter
    def template(self) -> None:
        self.__template = None
        return

    def f1(self) -> None:
        self.template = DocxTemplate(self.filename)
```